# Status corresponding to Minimum value

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have a table as given below. There can be multiple cancellations for each FundingID. I want to select the FundingCancellationReason corrersponding to minimum date for each funding. I wrote a query as follows. It is an SQL error

1) Could you please help me to avoid the SQL Error?

2) Is there any better logic to achieve the same?

```
CREATE TABLE #FundingCancellation(
[FundingCancellationID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FundingID] INT ,
FundingCancellationDt SMALLDATETIME ,
FundingCancellationReason VARCHAR(50)
) 


SELECT        FundingID, 
              MIN(FundingCancellationDt),
              ( SELECT FundingCancellationReason 
                FROM #FundingCancellation FC2 
                WHERE FC1.FundingID = FC2.FundingID
                AND FC2.FundingCancellationDt = MIN(FundingCancellationDt)
              ) [Reason Corresponding Minimum Date] 
FROM #FundingCancellation FC1
GROUP BY FundingID
```

-- An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

I have seen the similar approach working in a somewhat complex query. So I believe tehre will be a way to correct my query

Thanks
Lijo

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the Reason (and any other columns you may want) for each minimum date for each FundingID:

```
SELECT FC1.FundingID, FC1.FundingCancellationDt, 
         FC1.FundingCancellationReason, FC1.OtherColumn1, FC1.Other...
FROM #FundingCancellation FC1
JOIN
(
    SELECT FundingID, MIN(FundingCancellationDt) as 'MinDate'
    FROM #FundingCancellation
    GROUP BY FundingID
) AS Grouped ON (Grouped.FundingID = FC1.FundingID 
                   AND (Grouped.MinDate = FC1.FundingCancellationDt 
                        OR Grouped.MinDate IS NULL))
```

Note that if a given FundingID has more than one row with the same FundingCancellationDt (and it is the minimum), this will return ALL reasons for that minimum date.

The "OR Grouped.MinDate IS NULL" allows for null dates.

If you have duplicate minimum dates for a FundingID and you still want only one of the Reasons for each minimum, then use this:

```
SELECT FundingID, MinDate,
    (SELECT TOP 1 FundingCancellationReason 
        FROM #FundingCancellation 
        WHERE FundingCancellationDt = Grouped.MinDate) as 'Reason'
FROM 
(
    SELECT FundingID, MIN(FundingCancellationDt) as 'MinDate'
    FROM #FundingCancellation
    GROUP BY FundingID
) AS Grouped
```